# smartphone app that detects users location

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, blackberry, smartphone

I am going to soon make a website idea expanded to smartphone apps.  These apps will need to know the location of the user in question. I am doing a lot of research before I delve into these projects.  I will need to make android , iphone, and blackberry apps for this idea.  My question is, will I be able track these users location using the programming abilities these phones allow.  Also how legal is this is; it something the user has to agree to. Basically I need to know their location to verify if they are in the place they say they are in.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the userlocation using the Geolocation API that is available in mobile browsers.  They will have to grant your application permission to use it though.

A tutorial on how to use the API can be found here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/geolocation/trip_meter/

Answer (score 1):

With Android your app must outline all of the required permissions.  Such as:

`<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    ...
</manifest>`

On install the user is notified and must accept the permissions that your app requests in order to use the app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, yes it's legal, yes you will need the user's permission (at least on iOS)

Comment: On android the user needs to give the app permission to use location during installation of the app.